# pynetdicom send_c_find How to get the output?

Tags: python

I am using pynetdicom library to get patient information and Orthanc as pac server

I have this code

```
from pydicom.dataset import Dataset

from pynetdicom import AE, debug_logger
from pynetdicom.sop_class import PatientRootQueryRetrieveInformationModelFind

debug_logger()

ae = AE()
ae.add_requested_context(PatientRootQueryRetrieveInformationModelFind)

# Create our Identifier (query) dataset
ds = Dataset()
ds.SOPClassesInStudy = ''
ds.PatientID = '123'
ds.PatientName = ''
ds.StudyInstanceUID = ''
ds.QueryRetrieveLevel = 'STUDY'
ds.StudyID= ''
ds.StudyDate= ''

# Associate with the peer AE at IP 127.0.0.1 and port 11112
assoc = ae.associate("127.0.0.1", 4242)
if assoc.is_established:
    # Send the C-FIND request
    responses = assoc.send_c_find(ds, PatientRootQueryRetrieveInformationModelFind)
    
    print(ds)
    for (status, dataset) in responses:
        if status:
            print('C-FIND query status: 0x{0:04X}'.format(status.Status))
        else:
            print('Connection timed out, was aborted or received invalid response')

    # Release the association
    assoc.release()
else:
    print('Association rejected, aborted or never connected')`
and the output is this:
```

```
: pydicom.read_dataset() TransferSyntax="Little Endian Explicit"
I: 
I: # Response Identifier
I: (0008,0005) CS [ISO_IR 100]                             # 1 SpecificCharacterSet
I: (0008,0020) DA [20231206]                               # 1 StudyDate
I: (0008,0052) CS [STUDY]                                  # 1 QueryRetrieveLevel
I: (0008,0054) AE [CLLSPS]                                 # 1 RetrieveAETitle
I: (0008,0062) UI [1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.3.1]            # 1 SOPClassesInStudy
I: (0010,0010) PN [Andres]                      # 1 PatientName
I: (0010,0020) LO [464646]                                 # 1 PatientID
I: (0020,000D) UI [123213131]              # 1 StudyInstanceUID
I: (0020,0010) SH [20231206151403]                         # 1 StudyID
I: `
I
```

only need to be able to save the StudyInstanceUID field, is this possible?

I tried using dataset but I got no results, I also read that c-find does not return data, but nevertheless I see people who use it and can obtain data